# Why does new ArrayList<>().add(someObject) work in a lambda?

Tags: java, arraylist, lambda

The following line of code (using an ArrayList.forEach) compiles and runs...

Please note the  **new ArrayList<>()).add...**  which is what I'm interested in.

```
c.getMembers().forEach(m -> retVal.computeIfAbsent(m.getMemberGid(), v -> new ArrayList<>()).add(c.getClusterGid()));
```

To avoid confusion, retVal is defined as a HashMap on a previous line, thus the "computeIfAbsent"

However, the next line of code does not work and gives a (not surprising) error about return types not matching...

```
List<Gid> list = new ArrayList<>().add(new Gid());
```

The object types (Gid etc) aren't important - I'm just wondering why it works in the first forEach / lambda line?

Does the lambda code do an Arrays.asList or something similar under the covers?  What am I not understanding here...?

Comment: The lambda is not the difference. You can do `new ArrayList<Gid>().add(new Gid())` all you like; you just can't assign the result to a `List` variable because `add` does not return a list.

Comment: You're missing a critical `)` there.

Comment: "*I'm just wondering why it works in the first forEach / lambda line?*" but what makes you think it shouldn't be working?

Comment: What makes me think it shouldn't be working is that I cannot do this:  ArrayList<Gid> list = new ArrayList<Gid>().add(new Gid());  But it seems that the "problem" is that it cannot be done on an instantiation of a List or an ArrayList because - as @khelwood says, it (the .add() ) doesn't return a List or an ArrayList, simply a boolean...  Many thanks for the helpful comments.

Comment: And where exactly are you doing such thing in first example? Notice that you are not invoking `.computeIfAbsent(... , v -> new ArrayList<>().add(...))` but `.computeIfAbsent(... , v -> new ArrayList<>()).add(...)` - you are calling `add` on *result of computeIfAbsent*, not inside of it.

Comment: @Pshemo -- that hit the nail on the head for me.  The "why" of why it works in the first line of code.  At that point it's essentially myArrayList.add(Gid)... the result of the computeIfAbsent....

Answer (score 0):

Method **List::add()** doesn't return list itself. It returns **boolean** which cannot be casted to List

Answer (score 0):

## Why does computeIfAbsent work?

When you call [`computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html), you pass the following parameters:

```
V computeIfAbsent(K key, Function<? super K,? extends V> mappingFunction)
```

This method returns the type of the map value. Given your second argument `v -> new ArrayList<>()` your value type is probably **ArrayList** or **List**. So if the key exists, then this returns the corresponding list.  If the key does not exist, then it returns a new ArrayList.

## Why doesn't the second line work?

You create a new ArrayList and immediately call [`add`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add-E-). As you can see from the method definition:

```
boolean add(E e)
```

it returns a boolean, not a List.

If you are interested in creating a new list of elements on the spot, you can use [`Arrays.asList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)):

```
List<Gid> list = Arrays.asList(new Gid(), new Gid());
```

Note that this creates a fixed sized ArrayList (you can't add elements to this list).  To get around this, use:

```
List<Gid> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new Gid(), new Gid()));
```

which copies the fixed sized list into a new ArrayList.